# jQuery and Ajax not working $.on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when I click on Clear button, all fields in the form to be cleared.
The ajax request is only replacing the form from the tag `<form>` to `</form>`.
When it is clicked on Clear button, the console output is working.

I have the following form:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 formWrapper">
    <form data-th-fragment="layoutForm" id="layoutForm" class="form-horizontal" data-th-object="${layout}" data-th-action="@{/layouts/add}" method="POST" role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <input id="objectId" data-th-field="*{id}" type="hidden">
            <input data-th-if="*{filePath} !=null" data-th-field="*{filePath}" type="text" hidden="hidden">
            <label for="layoutName" >Layout name</label>
            <input data-th-field="*{name}" id="layoutName" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="status">Status</label>
                <select id="status" data-th-field="*{status}"class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Active</option>
                    <option value="0">Blocked</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label for="exhibitorName">Exhibitor</label>
                <select data-th-field="*{exhibitor}" name="exhibitorName"  id="exhibitorName" class="form-control">
                    <option data-th-each="exhibitor : ${exhibitorsList}" data-th-value="${exhibitor.id}" data-th-text="${exhibitor.exhibitorName}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-lg-3">
                <input id="clearForm" type="reset" value="Clear" class="form-control btn-lg btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4">
                <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Add" class="form-control btn-lg btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The form looks something like this:
[image]

The jQuery is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formWrapper').on('click','#clearForm', function (event) {
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
        console.log("ASD");
    });
});
```

The snipped is how I replace the form:

```
$("body").on('click','#editLayout', function(event){
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url : "/layouts/edit/" + $(this).data("id"),
        dataType : "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#layoutForm").replaceWith(data);
            $('#submitButton').val('Edit').addClass('btn-warning').removeClass('btn-success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just use a `<input type="reset" value="Clear" />`? No JS required

Comment: Because it is still doesn't work. It works only before the Ajax request.

Comment: Then provide a _working_ code snippet.

Comment: Can you provide the details of how you replace `.formWrapper` in your ajax call.

Comment: I edited the question with the snippet from the ajax call

Comment: try this: $(document).on('click','#clearForm', function (event)

Comment: So using `.replaceWith`, you are *replacing* `.formWrapper` - so your previous `$(".formWrapper").on(...` no longer works as that `.formWrapper` has been replaced.   Pick something higher or replace the contents of formWrapper not formWrapper itself.

Comment: Or just rewite the click event after you've replaced the html.

Comment: refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zLLn/

Comment: Pretty sure it's to do with *how* you replace your form, but your replace is `$("#layoutForm").replaceWith` so your delegated event handler should still work.  Try changing the event handler from `$(".formWrapper").on` to `$(document).on("click", "#clearForm"...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

or

```
$('#form_id')[0].reset();
```

A reset button doesn't need any script at all (or name or id):

```
<input type="reset">
```

and you're done. But if you really must use a script, note that every form control has a form property that references the form it's in, so you could do:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.reset();">
```

But a reset button is a far better choice.

Comment: I've tried every each, but it reset everything except the Layout name :) The value is still the same...

Comment: It works only if it is before ajax :) Afteer I call the ajax, and the fields are populated it doesn't work.

Comment: try this:  $('input[type="text"],texatrea, select', this).val(''); other wise $('form#layoutForm input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');

Comment: Thanks, it works with $('form#layoutForm input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $('#clearForm').reset(); or $('#clearForm')[0].reset();